# Fetch last ID where column is equal to a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I get confused on a sql statement and I kind of need your help.

Below are my table entitled (tblfood) contents:

```
ID  Food_Name           Main_Ingredient  Drink
1   Ham n Coke          Ham              Coke
2   Cheese n Tea        Cheese           Ice Tea
3   Ham n Coke          Ham              Coke
4   Ham n Coke          Ham              Coke
5   Chicken Sandwich    Chicken          None
6   Chicken Sandwich    Chicken          None
7   Cheese n Tea        Cheese           Ice Tea
8   Chicken n Coke      Chicken          Coke
9   Chicken Sandwich    Chicken          None
10  Cheese n Tea        Cheese           Ice Tea
```

I want to get the `ID` of the last entered `Food_Name` with `Chicken Sandwich`, which is 10. And if I get the last entered `Food_Name` with `Chicken n Coke`, it would display 9.

My first try goes like this:

```
Select id 
from tblfood 
where Food_Name='Chicken Sandwich';
```

But with this code, I believe it will display all the IDs where the Food_Name is equal to Chicken Sandwich.

How should I display only the last entered ID?

Comment: How about you make an attempt? The best way to learn is by doing.

Comment: Is `ID` an autoincrement field or is it entered manually? If it is entered manually there is no way to know the sequence in which data was entered into the table.

Comment: @unlimit its auto increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, selecting the max id considering you want a single id not multiple if you want multiple you need to rely on Order By clause solution.

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM tblfood 
WHERE Food_Name='Chicken Sandwich';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID 
FROM tblfood 
WHERE  Food_Name = 'Chicken Sandwich' 
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id
FROM tblfood 
WHERE Food_Name='Chicken Sandwich' 
ORDER BY id desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM tblfood 
WHERE Food_Name='Chicken Sandwich' 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Include a datetime entered field in your database table as 'DateOfEntry'
2. In your select statement select by max timestamp which would give you the latest entry.

`Select id from tblfood where Food_Name='Chicken Sandwich' and dateofentry in(select max(dateofentry) from tblfood) ';`